# How to get current console foreground/background colors in C#?

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I get current console colors (foreground/background)?

I have a method to output single line with changed foreground:

```
    public void ColorLine(string line, System.ConsoleColor foreground)
    {
        // maybe save original foreground color here

        // then change it 
        System.Console.ForegroundColor = foreground;

            // write line
            System.Console.WriteLine(line);

        // set original color
        System.Console.ForegroundColor = // original foreground color;
    }
```

Comment: use `Console.ForegroundColor` and store it in variable like `var currentColor = Console.ForegroundColor;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// save original foreground color here
ConsoleColor currentForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;


// set original color
Console.ForegroundColor = currentForeground
```